# Windows Phone programmatically connecting two devices and mirroring the screen

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

We can connect two or more iOS devices(iPhone and iPad both) programmatically via bluetooth and replicate the app's screen on multiple devices using GameKit in iOS. I searched on net if any API supports this kind of feature in Windows Phone 7/8, but I didnt find any luck. Please tell me if it is possible, if yes which API does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish such functionality only with Windows Phone 8 API. Take a look on Bluetooth API description here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx. `StreamSocket` can be useful to replicate the app's screen.